# Can not see the Firefox UI

Tags: windows, firefox

a fantastic problem: I tried to open my Firefox, but could not see its UI(the brower).
Meanwhile, I found the running process of Firefox in task manager.

How could this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to seem more responsive, sometimes Firefox will close the application window, but still be doing work in the background (e.g. saving your session, releasing resources, etc...) after you close the last window.

If it seems like Firefox has become unresponsive, you can just manually kill the task & restart the application.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I have tried what you described to do. I killed the task and restarted the firefox, but the UI kept missing. I even reinstalled the application but encountered the same thing. Any other idea?

Comment: I hate to resort to the boiler plate question, but have you tried restarting the computer? Perhaps there's something lingering that a reboot will fix.

Comment: The [Firefox Support Site](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-wont-start-find-solutions#w_no-error-message) also has some suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue, assuming the reboot doesn't resolve it.